# Python - Selenium webdriver set up-Message: session not created

Tags: python, google-chrome

I am setting up  python-selenium-webdriver, getting this error consistently irrespective of chrome driver update Message: session not created

I have been tried downgrading chrome and alternate Firefox versions, both didn't work.

Expected result: Chrome should be launched.

Actual: exception occurring.

Comment: Hi @kalai please can you give more info about what you are trying to do? Versions? Maybe a screenshot. Is this the full error message?

Comment: Hi Noraj.. I am trying to run a open browser test case in this suite. Chrome version-74. chrome driver version also - 74.

Comment: You have to put information in your post by editing it, not in comment. To learn more check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask